# Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement "in Entity Framework core"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here's my code:

```
 var result = dbContext.Specialty.OrderByDescending(u => u.IdS)
            .Skip(20)
            .Take(10)
            .AsEnumerable();
```

**Error**:

> **Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement**

Comment: Are you connecting to a SQL 2008 database or SQL 2017 database (check your connection string)?

Comment: @mjwills SQL 2008

Comment: You need to change your connection string to point to a SQL 2017 database.

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2008 *and* 2017 on your system, at least *one of them* must be using an explicit **instance name** - just connect to that **SQL Server instance** using your connection string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a compatibility setting (`UseRowNumberForPaging`) for this which can be configured either in the DbContext itself:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var coonectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=AppDb01;Integrated Security=True";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(coonectionString, builder => builder.UseRowNumberForPaging());
    }
```

Or as a part of the Startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var coonectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=AppDb01;Integrated Security=True";
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(coonectionString, builder => builder.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

`UseRowNumberForPaging` [was removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#userownumberforpaging-has-been-removed) in EF Core 3.x, method is marked as obsolete. However, you can use `EfCore3.SqlServer2008Query` package instead. There are 2 packages available in Nuget, one for >= .NET 5.0, other one is for >= .NET Core 3.1

[image]

Usage:

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o => 
       o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))
        .ReplaceService<IQueryTranslationPostprocessorFactory, SqlServer2008QueryTranslationPostprocessorFactory>());
```

Comment: Do you know where I can get the source code of that nuget?

Comment: yes the package works but we don't know how safe it is

Answer (score 10):

For anyone using .Net 6
I found this package **EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging 0.3.0**: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging/

Base on the github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16400

Thank you **Rwing**, whoever you are, you're a hero!

Answer (score 3):

Just detailing @jawid-hassim answer:

Using .NET 6 + EF Core 6 + SQL Server 2008, you can install the package bellow (wich has a GitHub repository, so the code can be checked for safety).

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging/

After installing the package, in Program.cs add:

```
using EntityFrameworkCore.UseRowNumberForPaging;
```

Then replace your DbContext service configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

For:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o => o.UseRowNumberForPaging()));
```

Comment: Thanks, author now added .Net 7 Support 

Answer (score 1):

sql server 2008 not support from my query

**solution**:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var coonectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=AppDb01;Integrated Security=True";
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(coonectionString);
    }
}
```

Value connection string to the Target server
and also inject the settings , The sample code is in the default ASP NET Core project format.